# What are all the admin mods available for Counter Strike 1.6?

Tags: mods, counter-strike

I used AMX mod in CS 1.6 before. I want to know, what are all the mod's available now for free of cost?

Providing their links also appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I think your best option is [AMX Mod X](http://www.amxmodx.org/). The developers of AMX Mod (of which you have experience) joined the AMX Mod X project [some time ago](http://forums.alliedmods.net/showthread.php?t=49476&highlight=amxmod). There is an almost comprehensive range of free plugins written by the community that add to the core functionality. I've found that their [forums](http://forums.alliedmods.net/forumdisplay.php?f=3) are generally helpful if you can't find what you want or need help with configuration.

Some people still use [AdminMod](http://www.adminmod.org/), though I think it's fair to say that they belong to a small minority.

Comment: I know a few of the AMXX developers, and they are *ridiculously* good coders. You wouldn't believe the amount of ASM-hacking they had to do to get access to some of those server-side events.  Definitely your best choice.